# Visual Studio Multi Forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

So i have a question regarding a program I built.  First of all my textbook is not a good resource.  Second of all, I have everything done, "I Think", except getting the total cost to flow into the correct label.  So basically I have two forms, the first has my information and the second is where you select what you want to attend at a conference.  Everything works when I run this except for the total does not cross from the options form to the main form.  I am at my wits end.  Any suggestions?

Main Form Code:

```
Public Class MainForm

    Private Sub selectButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles selectButton.Click
        ' Create an instance of the Conference options form
        Dim frmOptions As New Conference_Options

        ' Display the form
        frmOptions.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub exitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles exitButton.Click
        ' Close the form
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub resetButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles resetButton.Click
        ' Clear everything
        nameTextBox.Clear()
        companyTextBox.Clear()
        addressTextBox.Clear()
        cityTextBox.Clear()
        stateTextBox.Clear()
        zipTextBox.Clear()
        phoneTextBox.Clear()
        emailTextBox.Clear()
        totalLabel.Text = ""
    End Sub
    End Class
```

Options Form Code:

```
Public Class Conference_Options

    Function TotalCost(ByRef dblTotalCost)
        Dim dblRegistration As Double
        Dim dblDinnerandReg As Double
        Dim dblPreCon As Double

        'conference registration
        If registrationCheckBox.Checked = True Then
            dblRegistration = 895
        Else
            dblRegistration = 0
        End If

        'dinner and keynote speech
        If dinnerCheckBox.Checked = True Then
            dblDinnerandReg = 30
        Else
            dblDinnerandReg = 0
        End If

        'optional preconference workshop
        If preconferenceListBox.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            dblPreCon = 295
        ElseIf preconferenceListBox.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            dblPreCon = 295
        ElseIf preconferenceListBox.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            dblPreCon = 395
        ElseIf preconferenceListBox.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
            dblPreCon = 395
        ElseIf preconferenceListBox.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
            dblPreCon = 0
        End If
        dblTotalCost = dblRegistration + dblDinnerandReg + dblPreCon
        Return dblTotalCost

    End Function
    Private Sub closeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles closeButton.Click

        ' Close the form
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Function totalLabel() As Object
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function
    End Class
```

I hope you see that I did actually put forth a great deal of effort, but I am struggling to make it work.

Comment: Did you try exposing TotalCost as public property(set its value from within the function) in Options form and calling it like: `frmOptions.TotalCost` , since you already hold an instance of it in Main form ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this kind of problem is treated with a form having two buttons, one labeled "Confirm" and with the DialogResult property set to DialogResult.OK and the other labeled with "Cancel" and with the DialogResult property set to DialogResult.Cancel

Now when your user presses the Confirm button you could execute the code in your TotalCost function but save the result in a global property of your form

Something like this

```
Dim totalCost as Decimal
Public Readonly Property TotalCost as Decimal
     Get
          Return totalCost
     End Get
End Property

Private Sub confirmButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles confirmButton.Click

   totalCost = CalcTotalCost()

End Sub

Private Function CalcTotalCost() as Decimal

    ' This is your previous function TotalCost renamed to
    ' avoid conflicts with the property (and now it is private)

    Dim decRegistration As Decimal
    Dim decDinnerandReg As Decimal
    Dim decPreCon As Decimal

    'conference registration
    If registrationCheckBox.Checked = True Then
        decRegistration = 895
    Else
        decRegistration = 0
    End If

    'dinner and keynote speech
    If dinnerCheckBox.Checked = True Then
        decDinnerandReg = 30
    Else
        decDinnerandReg = 0
    End If

    'optional preconference workshop
    If preconferenceListBox.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        decPreCon = 295
    ElseIf preconferenceListBox.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        decPreCon = 295
    ElseIf preconferenceListBox.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        decPreCon = 395
    ElseIf preconferenceListBox.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        decPreCon = 395
    ElseIf preconferenceListBox.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        decPreCon = 0
    End If

    Return decRegistration + decDinnerandReg + decPreCon
End Function
```

Now you could call your frmOptions in this way and get back the value

```
Public Class MainForm

    Private Sub selectButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles selectButton.Click
        ' Create an instance of the Conference options form
        Using frmOptions = New Conference_Options
            ' Display the form and check if the user confirms
            DialogResult result = frmOptions.ShowDialog()
            If result = DialogResult.OK Then
                ' Read the value calculated in the Confirm event handler
                Dim total = frmOptions.TotalCost
            End If
        End Using ' Closing and destroying the options form
    End Sub
```

Notice that I have changed your variables from Double to Decimal because it is more appropriate to use this type when dealing with money values.